# Hadoop previous.checkpoint location

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I tried hadoop-1.0.3 as well as 1.0.4. Both under pseudo cluster mode.

My understanding is that the previous.checkpoint directory should be created under secondary name node designated by "fs.checkpoint.dir"? On all occasions I am finding it under the namenode directory designated by "dfs.name.dir". It this something to do with Pseudo mode or my understanding is wrong? Can someone please help!

Below is my **hdfs-site.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hadoop/lab/hdfs/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hadoop/lab/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.checkpoint.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hadoop/lab/hdfs/secnamenode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

The below is high level directory structure for the daemons

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~/lab/hdfs$ ls -l
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 6 hadoop hadoop 4096 Mar 14 03:41 datanode
drwxrwxr-x 5 hadoop hadoop 4096 Mar 14 03:41 namenode
drwxrwxr-x 4 hadoop hadoop 4096 Mar 14 04:46 secnamenode
```

Below is the NameNode directory details

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~/lab/hdfs$ ls -l namenode
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 hadoop hadoop 4096 Mar 14 04:46 current
drwxrwxr-x 2 hadoop hadoop 4096 Mar 14 03:13 image
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop    0 Mar 14 03:41 in_use.lock
drwxrwxr-x 2 hadoop hadoop 4096 Mar 14 03:34 previous.checkpoint
```

Below is the SNN directory details

```
hadoop@ubuntu:~/lab/hdfs$ ls -l secnamenode
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 hadoop hadoop 4096 Mar 14 04:46 current
drwxrwxr-x 2 hadoop hadoop 4096 Mar 14 03:46 image
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hadoop hadoop    0 Mar 14 03:41 in_use.lock
```

If you need any further details please let me know.

Thanks
Rags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done an extensive and desperate search about this. There seems to be a long pending Bug [HDFS-1839](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-1839) which removes *previous.checkpoint* directory from the *SecondaryNameNode*. The same bug might be responsible for having this directory created under the *NameNode*.

I have seen all the versions of hadoop so far and under all these the *previous.checkpoint* directory is consistently being created under the *NameNode*.

Hope soon this bug will be fixed or Apache Hadoop clarifies why directory is created under NameNode